# How to change the "current" class to "active" in KNPMenuBundle

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle

I was wondering, what is the best way to change the "current" class to be "active" so Bootstrap will work correctly with it?

I thought about copying and overriding the knp_menu_html.twig but i think its not the best way...

Anyway better doing it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can pass it like that:

```
{{ knp_menu_render('AcmeDemoBundle:Builder:mainMenu', {'currentClass': 'active'}) }}
```

Answer (score 26):

To apply default options in all your application, you can set the `knp_menu.renderer.twig.options` parameter like this:

```
// app/config/services.yml
parameters:
    knp_menu.renderer.twig.options:
        currentClass: active
```

Default options of the `Knp\Menu\Renderer\TwigRenderer` are:

```
    $this->defaultOptions = array_merge(array(
        'depth' => null,
        'matchingDepth' => null,
        'currentAsLink' => true,
        'currentClass' => 'current',
        'ancestorClass' => 'current_ancestor',
        'firstClass' => 'first',
        'lastClass' => 'last',
        'template' => $template,
        'compressed' => false,
        'allow_safe_labels' => false,
        'clear_matcher' => true,
        'leaf_class' => null,
        'branch_class' => null,
    ), $defaultOptions);
```

Comment: Is it possible to set these options inside MenuBuilder class?

Comment: Not directly. Event if you injected the "knp_menu.renderer.twig" service (the "Knp\Menu\Renderer\TwigRenderer" class above) in your menu builder, there are no mutators for default options. You could eventually implement some mutators yourself by overriding the renderer class with the parameter "knp_menu.renderer.twig.class"