# Override options in knp menu bundle for symfony2

Tags: symfony, overriding, knpmenubundle

From the default knp menu bundle template:

```
{%- elseif matcher.isAncestor(item, options.matchingDepth) %}
    {%- set classes = classes|merge([options.ancestorClass]) %}
```

options.ancestorClass is equal to 'current_ancestor'. Is there a way to override this? I dont want to copy the wohle block item code which covers 50 lines of code, from which I only need to change one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply default options in all your application, you can set the `knp_menu.renderer.twig.options` parameter like this:

```
// app/config/services.yml
parameters:
    knp_menu.renderer.twig.options:
        currentClass: active
```

Default options of the `Knp\Menu\Renderer\TwigRenderer` are:

```
    $this->defaultOptions = array_merge(array(
        'depth' => null,
        'matchingDepth' => null,
        'currentAsLink' => true,
        'currentClass' => 'current',
        'ancestorClass' => 'current_ancestor',
        'firstClass' => 'first',
        'lastClass' => 'last',
        'template' => $template,
        'compressed' => false,
        'allow_safe_labels' => false,
        'clear_matcher' => true,
        'leaf_class' => null,
        'branch_class' => null,
    ), $defaultOptions);
```

Try

```
{{ knp_menu_render('AcmeDemoBundle:Builder:mainMenu', {'ancestorClass': 'your-class'}) }}
```

From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120855/how-to-change-the-current-class-to-active-in-knpmenubundle)

Comment: Thanks, I choosed the second approach.